# How to set axis in tensorflow C++ API such as python

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, sum, mean

I use tensorflow in python easily for math ops such as reduce_sum or reduce_mean like this

```
array = np.ndarray(shape=(2, 2, 3), buffer=np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
                                                     [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]]),
                   dtype=int)
mean = tf.reduce_mean(array)
sum = tf.reduce_sum(array)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(mean))
    print(sess.run(sum))
```

from this, I can get the mean and sum of a tensor into one value, howerver, when I do these ops in C++, I get some problem, like this

```
Sum(root.WithOpName("sum"), tensor_input, 1)
```

In this example, the second param tensor_input is a tensor of shape [1, 160, 160, 3].
Differently,I have to set the third param to a number in range of (-rank, rank), but this can not get my wanted result for suming all values in the tensor such as in python, rather than, it Computes the sum of elements across dimensions of a tensor.  so how can I get the same result such as in python for suming all values into one value.
It would be helpful if anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, when you want to reduce your sum or mean result, if you do this on a tensor in shapr [1, 160, 160, 3], you can use like this

```
Sum(root.WithOpName("sum"), tensor_input, {0, 1, 2, 3})
```

The last prama is range of (0, rank(tensor_input))